# Solving a system of differential equations including a discrete time function

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, discrete

Given a graph of $N$ nodes, I would like to solve the following set of differential equations:
[image]

where $G_i'(r,s)\triangleq \frac{d G_i(r,s)}{ds} = \Big(1-L_i(t) - I_i(t)-B_i(t) - C_i(t)\Big)\sum_{j=1}^N b_{i,j}\sqrt{G_i(r,s)}$.

I have implemented the first, second and fourth equations using Table as follows:

```
eqns = {
Table[Derivative[1][L[i]][t] == (1 - L[i][t] - I[i][t] - B[i][t] - C[i][t]) * Sum[a[[i]][[j]] * (bL * L[j][t] + bI * I[j][t]), {j, 1, N}] - (g1 + a1) * L[i][t], {i, 1, N}],
Table[Derivative[1][I[i]][t] == a1 * L[i][t] - n1 * I[i][t], {i, 1, N}],
Table[Derivative[1][C[i]][t] == a2 * B[i][t] - n2 * C[i][t], {i, 1, N}],
Table[Derivative[1][B[i]][t] == Integrate[...]]};
```

I need help on implementing the equation involving $G'(r,s)$. Also, $a_{i,j}$ and $b_{i,j}$ are defined as follows:

```
g1 = RandomGraph[WattsStrogatzGraphDistribution[N, 0.4]];
g2 = RandomGraph[WattsStrogatzGraphDistribution[N, 0.4]];
a = AdjacencyMatrix[g1];
b = AdjacencyMatrix[g2];
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define your equations making use of partial derivative 
 function D[f(x,y),x] instead of the one argument Derivative[n][f(x),x]
It's not clear in the third equation what is the integration variable, let us just assume the u variable. So, one gets

```
eqns = {
   Table[Derivative[1][L[i]][
      t] == (1 - L[i][t] - I[i][t] - B[i][t] - C[i][t])*
       Sum[a[[i]][[j]]*(bL*L[j][t] + bI*I[j][t]), {j, 1, N}] - (g1 + 
         a1)*L[i][t], {i, 1, N}],
   Table[Derivative[1][I[i]][t] == a1*L[i][t] - n1*I[i][t], {i, 1, N}],
   Table[Derivative[1][B[i]][t] == 
     Integrate[((eL*Derivative[1][L[i]][u] + 
           eI*Derivative[1][I[i]][u])*
         D[G[i][u, t - u], s] - (g2 + a2) B[i][t]), {u, 0, t}], {i, 1,
      N}],
   Table[Derivative[1][C[i]][t] == a2*B[i][t] - n2*C[i][t], {i, 1, N}],
   Table[D[G[i][r, s], 
      s] == (1 - L[i][t] - I[i][t] - B[i][t] - C[i][t])*
      Sum[b[[i]][[j]]*Sqrt[G[i][r, s]], {j, 1, N}], {i, 1, N}]

   };


g1 = RandomGraph[WattsStrogatzGraphDistribution[N, 0.4]];
g2 = RandomGraph[WattsStrogatzGraphDistribution[N, 0.4]];
a = AdjacencyMatrix[g1];
b = AdjacencyMatrix[g2];

n1 = NDSolve[eqns, Table[L[k], {k, K1}], {t, 50}];
n2 = NDSolve[eqns, Table[B[k], {k, K1}], {t, 50}];
n5 = Table[Sum[L[k][t], {k, 1, K1}]/K1, {k, K1}] /. n1;
n6 = Table[Sum[B[k][t], {k, 1, K1}]/K1, {k, K1}] /. n2;
plot1 = Plot[{n5, n6}, {t, 0, 50}, PlotStyle -> {Red, Blue}, PlotRange -> All]
```

From here it's missing define the variables a1,a2,bL,bI,eL,eI,n2.

Comment: The code seems to be working. However, I need to plot the numerical values for L[i] and B[i] as functions of t. The following is the code, but gives error:
    n1 = NDSolve[eqns, Table[L[k], {k, K1}], {t, 50}];
    n2 = NDSolve[eqns, Table[B[k], {k, K1}], {t, 50}];
    n5 = Table[Sum[L[k][t], {k, 1, K1}]/K1, {k, K1}] /. n1;
    n6 = Table[Sum[B[k][t], {k, 1, K1}]/K1, {k, K1}] /. n2;
    plot1 = Plot[{n5, n6}, {t, 0, 50}, PlotStyle -> {Red, Blue}, PlotRange -> All]

Comment: Try to change Integrate[] by its numerical form NIntegrate and implement some integration strategy/role to perform this difficult task. You still need to define the variables above mentioned.